# What happens to the stardrive of a Long Ranged Shuttle?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-motion-picture

Surak was a long ranged shuttle seen in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*:

[image]

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Long_range_shuttle) describes a long ranged shuttle as:

> These long range shuttles featured a detachable fuselage pod, capable
>   of acting as an independent craft from the stardrive section.

Here it is separating to deliver Spock to the Enterprise:
[image]

**What happens to the stardrive section at this point?** Is there a pilot in there to guide it back post separation?

Comment: Does my answer below solve your question, or were you hoping for something more? :-)

Answer (score 6):

The stardrive section (referred to by its designers Andrew Probert and Richard Taylor as the *warp sled*) can **fly and park itself on autopilot**. As Probert said:

> "At the time, I was intrigued by the idea of total instrument flying. Certainly 200 years from now such technology will be commonplace. [...] The sled, incidentally, parks relative to the Enterprise and automatically keeps station with it."
>   <sub>-- *Starlog*, issue 32, pp. 29-30</sub>

You can find this quote, along with lots of other info, [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Long_range_shuttle_model).

Comment: Is it just that you can't *admit* that you watch Star Trek? ;-)

Comment: @Praxis No, it's just that I can do research :-) I haven't seen [Superman](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103941/how-strong-would-clark-have-to-be-to-lift-the-school-bus-out-of-the-water/103944#103944) or [Star Wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104187/star-wars-the-empire-and-taxation/104188#104188) either.

Comment: I knew about you and Star Wars, but Superman too??  If only there was an "expert answer from non-expert" badge... ;-)

Comment: I think the expert answer makes him a non-non-expert. I just don't get why he takes the time to do the research and answer questions on things he doesn't watch... I think we all appreciate it, but I don't understand it. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. Does this help? http://stackexchange.com/users/4859979/rand-althor?tab=reputation I started answering such questions in September... ;-)